# transformar texto em link

Tags: php, regex

Eu estou tentando transformar o link de uma imagem na imagem dentro da tag, entretanto estou tendo dificuldades quando existe a imagem, o mesmo tento fazer com o link

no caso uso o código abaixo

```
$reply = preg_replace('#((http://|https://|//)([^\s]*)\.jpg|gif|png|JPG))#',  
'<img src="$1" alt="" width="" height="" />', $data['reply']);
```

Ele funciona muito bem quando o link é postado assim

```
http://wallpaper.ultradownloads.com.br/276255_Papel-de-Parede-Meme-Obama-Not-Bad_1280x1024.jpg
```

porém se no texto tiver algo assim

```
<img src="http://wallpaper.ultradownloads.com.br/276255_Papel-de-Parede-Meme-Obama-Not-Bad_1280x1024.jpg" >
```

ele vai tentar transformar também, como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: A titulo de curiosidade, um site muito bom para verificar as regEx: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 3):

Fica uma sugestão de alteração de código.

Teste assim:

```
preg_match('/(https?:\/\/[^\s\'\"]*)/', $data['reply'], $match);
$reply = '<img src="'.$match[0].'" alt="" width="" height="" />';
```

Exemplo: http://ideone.com/qpknsU

Eu acho esta maneira mais limpa. Primeiro extrair o url pretendido, depois concatenar na string.

Comment: Mas o texto tem mas coisas além do da URL inclusive outras URL que não são imagens e imagens dentro de tags

Comment: @DanielLemes, nesse caso coloque mais exemplos para eu ajustar a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o que pretende é pegar a url apenas de tags "anchor"  e quando executa o código ele pega tudo que é url.

Então só precisa de fazer esta pequena alteração ao código que o Sergio postou em cima

```
preg_match('/href="(https?:\/\/[^\s\'\"]*)/', $data['reply'], $match);
$reply = '<img src="'.$match[1].'" alt="" width="" height="" />';
```

Comment: Não, eu pretendo pegar um texto que contenha link de imagens e devolver o texto com as imagens dentro da tag img, além disso esse texto pode ou não ter link para url e imagens já dentro de tags e isso deve ser ignorado.